# Max-min and min-max equivalence for the optimization problem

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, maxima-minima, numerical-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have the following max-min problem:

$\underset{{\bf X}}{\max}  \underset{k}{\min} \|{\bf A}_k{\bf x}_k\|^2_2 $

where ${\bf X} = [{\bf x}_1, \dots, {\bf x}_K]\in \mathbb{C}^{N \times P}$ and ${\bf A}_k  = [{\bf a}_1, \dots, {\bf a}_M]^H \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$.

Now suppose I have a upper-bound for $|{\bf a}_m^H {\bf x}_k| \leq u_m$, then defining ${\bf U} = [{u}_1, \dots, {u}_M]^T \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times 1}$ can I write

$\underset{{\bf X}}{\max} \underset{k}{\min}\} \|{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k\|^2_2 \Leftrightarrow \underset{{\bf X}}{\min} \underset{k}{\max} {\| |{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k| - {\bf U}}\|^2_2$

That is to say, maximizing the minimum  $\|{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k\|^2_2$ over $k$ is equivalent to minimizing the maximum mathcing error between $( |{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k| - {\bf U})$ over $k$?

Edit: I have the following explanation for the equivalence of the two problems:

$|{\bf a}_m^H {\bf x}_k| \leq u_m \implies |{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k| \preccurlyeq {\bf U} \overset{(a)}\implies \underset{k}{\min} \|{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k\|^2_2 \Leftrightarrow \underset{k}{\max} {\| |{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k| - {\bf U}}\|^2_2, \; \forall {\bf X} \overset{(b)}\implies \underset{{\bf X}}{\max}\underset{k}{\min} \|{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k\|^2_2 \Leftrightarrow \underset{{\bf X}}{\min}  \underset{k}{\max}  {\| |{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k| - {\bf U}}\|^2_2$

Step (a) follows that the '$k$' with the minimum $\|{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k\|^2_2$ is equivalent to the '$k$' with the maximum total matching error between $|{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k|$ and ${\bf U}$, $\forall \; {\bf X}$. Subsequently step (b) originates from step (a) implying that ${\bf X}$ maximizing the minimum $\|{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k\|^2_2$ over the all the 'k' is equivalent to ${\bf X}$ minimizing the maximum total matching error between $|{\bf A}_k {\bf x}_k|$ and  ${\bf U}$ over the all the 'k'.

Comment: BTW in MathJax/LaTeX you can use command \max and \min: $\max$ and $\min$. (It's definitely shorter than $\text{max}$, and also provides correct spacing.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have changed the command to use max and min. Apart from that do you think my explanation for the equivalence of the max-min and min-max formulation is correct?